# G7 countries - Can India become a member of the Group 7 (G7)?

Tags: international-relations, india

[G7 countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_Seven_(disambiguation))

Can India become a member of G7 countries with the odd number 7 becoming a even number 8.

To become a member of the G7 will there be a casting of votes by the existing G7 countries members?

Comment: You can also  include possible advantages and benefits of becoming a G7-G8 member in question.

Comment: At this moment in time? No - the G7 countries are sanctioning Russia, but India keeps trading. In this respect, India is aligned with China, not the G7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The G7 became the G8 in 1997 when it admitted Russia, then it became the G7 again in 2014 when it expelled Russia.

If it chose to admit India, it would presumably be the G8 again (or the G9, G10... etc if it admitted other countries at the same time)

It isn't a democracy, so having an even or odd number of members doesn't matter.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/47th_G7_summit India was one of the the invited guests in 2021 G7 summit.

Answer (score 7):

The [G7/G8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_Seven) is a *structured series of intergovernmental conferences.* As such, it is no different from the [Visegrad Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visegr%C3%A1d_Group), or the [Quadrilateral Security Dialogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral_Security_Dialogue), or many others. New members can be admitted whenever the old members want to, and the name would be whatever the old and new members want to call it. So the question would be more like:

*What is the likelihood that the G7 members would recognize India as a useful addition to their conferences?*

- China has not been admitted. Obviously the Gross Domestic Product is not the key factor.
- Sweden has not been admitted. Obviously a stable and reputable democracy is not the key factor.

Looking at the G7 members, the pattern for membership would be leading industrial/financial powers which are also established democracies in the "Western pattern." Basically, when those seven finance ministers or heads of government meet, they speak for a sufficient group of regional and global powers to influence world events.

The admission of Russia did not *quite* match this pattern. It was more the expression of the *hope* that Russia would align with the other G8 members. This did not happen, and the G7 decided to meet without Russia again.

As to the decisionmaking on admissions, it isn't as if there was a formal organization with a charter. If one government invites the six others and they come, it is a G7 summit. If it were one government were to invite the six others plus India, it would be the G8 unless India was clearly labeled as a *special guest* or *observer*. Hypothetically, India could invite the seven old G7 members to a summit and call that G8 summit, and if they all attend it would be the G8.